# Rails Update method doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, edit, crud

I want to update a `prediction_config`, but something is going wrong. Here are the relevant methods in my controller:

```
def edit
    @prediction_config = PredictionConfigs.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @prediction_config = PredictionConfigs.find(params[:id])

    if @prediction_config.update_attributes(params[:prediction_config])
        redirect_to @prediction_config
    else 
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Here is my Model:

```
class PredictionConfigs < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :value

validates :name, presence: true
validates :value, :inclusion => {:in => [0,100]},
                  presence: true
end
```

What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: It is simply not updating the value, but everything loads properly.

Comment: what is it that's going wrong?

Comment: Do you have an error? What do you see in your log? Is the `PredictionConfig` valid?

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what `params[:prediction_config]` is.  Can you debug this and post the result.  If you don't have the tools for that, please provide the form in your edit view.  First guess is that you mean `:in => [0...100]` so the value is in a range, not either 0 or 100.

Comment: `update_attributes` takes a hash like `params`, not a single attribute value.

Comment: are you using Rails 4 or 3?

Comment: `params[:prediction_config` is a hash that contains `name` and `value`. Both are `attr_accessible` to `prediction_config`.

Also, I am using rails 3.2.11

Comment: check `@prediction_config.errors`

Comment: There is a 500 Internal Server error

Comment: So, what's causing it? Show us the stack trace.

Comment: (in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/app/assets/javascrip
ts/active_admin/lib/namespace.js.coffee)
Served asset /application-1dd0da1c7beee972b0cdecc75e5da5b2.js - 500 Internal Ser
ver Error

Comment: Usually there is more stack trace after the "500 Internal Server Error"  - that's the interesting part.  Ideally, update your original post with the stack trace.